# Updating JIRA issues from Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, jira, azure-pipelines

We are using JIRA cloud for issue handling. Our source code is in Azure Devops Repos, and we use Azure Devops Pipelines for build and release.

Is it possible to set it up, so that a JIRA issue is automatically transitioned into another status, when Azure Pipelines has completed a deployement to a specific environment?
The issue number is references in the Pull Request title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If manually add a variable to define the issue number in your pipeline is workable. You can try below to add a bash task at the end of your release pipeline and call Jira api to transition the issue status.

1. First define a variable for issue number, and one for transitionid if neccessary.
   [image]
2. Second add a bash task at the end of your release pipeline.
   [image]

Assume you know your transition ids. You can use below script.
click [here](https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens.) to get your api token for your Jira.

```
curl -D- -u "username:APIToken" -X POST --data '{"transition":{"id":"transitionid"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"  https://[accouint].atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/[issue-no]/transitions?transitionId?expand=transitions.fields
```

(To get transitionids use below api):

```
curl -D- -u "username:APIToken" -X GET https://[accouint].atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/[issue-no]/transitions?transitionId?expand=transitions.fields
```

Update:

Pull request title can be retrieved via below [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#gitpullrequest).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=5.1
```

Hope above is helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, that could be the way to update the issues. Azure Devops is already aware of which issues are related to a given release, since they can be shown, by looking at the release details. So maybe there is a way to get them using the Azure Devops REST API

Comment: You are correct, PR title can retrieved via rest api `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests/{pullRequestId}?api-version=5.1`

Comment: We can get the issues related to a release with this api call
`https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/workitems`
Not sure how to tie the pieces together though...